# sequence problems and partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

im doing an assignment and was asked a question about this sequence

$$\sum_{k=1}^n  a_n$$
where $a_n$ is a set of monotonicaly decreasing non negative numbers
$a_1$$\geqslant%$$a_2$$\geqslant%$$a_3$....$\geqslant%$$a_n$
and can be denoted as $s_n$

I'm trying to show that

$s_3$$\leqslant$$a_1$+$2a_2$
and that $s_7$$\leqslant$$a_1$+$2a_2$+$4a_4$

i know from a previous question that
$s_n$$\leqslant$$s_{(2^n-1)}$

i tried using the fact i know $a_1 +a_2$ $\gt$ $a_3$
but im really not sure what im doing with this question
any advice on this would be great

Answer (score 1):

$s_3=a_1+a_2+a_3\le a_1+a_2+a_2=a_1+2a_2$ (using the fact that $a_3\le a_2$ for the inequality step).

You can do an analogous thing for the other inequality.